# How to show Image in full screen from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that showing text and images from web.

I want to do it like when i tap on Image in UIWebView , i want to show it in Full Screen including Orientations.

so i tested with following codes.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL];

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
        UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

        GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
        vc.liftedImageView = imageView;

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;
    }

    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and showing error when i tap image in `UIWebView`.

```
2014-03-12 13:59:40.397 MMSP[1368:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Is there anyway to do like i said above?

Comment: i didn't set imageView frame becz GGFullScreenImageViewController can do it automatically

Comment: are you sure that url contains image data ?

Answer (score 1):

a) I think you should set the frame for GGFullscreenImageViewController

b) Generally (not having to do with your crash), i think you should **not** use [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL]; to load the image at this point. On clicking a link, it will wait until the image has downloaded, and then show it, resulting in a 'lag' for your user.

Instead, just hand over the URL to your GGFullscreenImageViewController, the view controller and have it display an activity indicator until it has downloaded the image.

Comment: how to show URL to GGFullScreenImageViewController directly?

Comment: My apologies, i assumed GGFullScreenImageViewController was a class you had written yourself. Since it is not, you can't seem to realize it the way mentioned. You can either modify the it's code from GitHub to allow this, or you ou can display an activity indicator in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method (ie, create a new semi-transparent view and show it) and load GGFullScreenImageViewController when done.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `UIImageView` setup on your `GGFullscreenImageViewController` then why not just create the `UIImage` and assign, instead of creating a new `UIImageView`. The image view instance in `liftedImageView` is lost when you assign newly created instance.

Just do this,

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
vc.liftedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Ideally, you should pass the image url to the `GGFullscreenImageViewController` by providing `initWithUrl:` method. Do the downloading of image **asynchronously** or you could use open source code which does this, ex: [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Hope this helps!